# Why does \mathrm{\varphi} work, but \text{\varphi} does not?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, greek

This:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\varphi}$
\end{document}
```

Versus:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\text{\varphi}$
\end{document}
```

The first works, the last does not. Why? Especially when defining macros with `\text` this can lead to problems. Any way around it?

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever why the second should work: `\text` is for inserting *text* in a math formula. The fact that `\mathrm{\phi}` works is just a coincidence, but the result is in no way different from `\phi`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\varphi` is a math symbol and requires math mode. Since `\mathrm` still "provides" math mode, `\varphi` doesn't complain. On the other hand, `\text` (from [`amstext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amstext); loaded by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) is a macro that makes the correct choice in font size when switching to text mode - super convenient when typesetting test in exponents/subscripts. However, it still switches to text mode.

If you which to use `\varphi` in text mode without having to switch to math mode explicitly, use something like

```
\newcommand{\textphi}{\ensuremath{\varphi}}
```

which will allow you to use `\textphi` in either text or math mode. The `\ensuremath` conditional switches to math mode only when necessary (when you're in text mode, say).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\textphi}{\ensuremath{\varphi}}
\begin{document}
$\varphi^\varphi\ \textphi^\textphi$\ \textphi\textsuperscript{\textphi}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `\varphi` is math mode only. As far as I’m concerned, there is no text mode alternative.

The only text mode alternative would be `\textphi`, but for using it you have to include the package `tipa`. Also, it’s just a plain normal phi.

Comment: Does \text{} leave math mode?

Comment: @FooBar That’s what `text` says, isn’t it? ;)

Comment: But `text` is a math mode command, so I'd assume it is fully math mode compatible. ;)

Comment: @FooBar Touché. Yet still, `text` is to use “words or phrases in a display.” (AMSmath documentation).